# LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to X at stream()....findAny() step (details inside the question)

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have solved my issue but I did not get anyway the reason of the failure I was getting.
I have a class:

```
public class A {
...some code where I got JSON that I need to map to an Object...
Then I was doing this:

String jsonString = response_I_got_via_RESTAssured.getBody();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Object> myObj = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<>(){});

}
```

After that, in my code I was getting a List that I was filtering via *stream().filter([by some rules]).findAny();*

While the code with ObjectMapper.... was **inside** the class as above I show in the code - all was working fine. Then I decided to refactor my code and moved this code to a separate helper class. The method moved looked like (pseudo code partially + I am skipping exception handling parts, fyi):

```
   public static <T> T method(RestAssured response) {

     String jsonString = response_I_got_via_RESTAssured.getBody();
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     return = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<>(){});
   }
```

But for this case I started to get 'Jackson: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to X' (popular issue), at the step after this method, when I was doing:

stream()
.filter()

**.findAny()**  < here this error occurred

I fixed my method by adding +1 param - TypeReference, I updated my method outside the class to the:

```
  public static <T> T method(RestAssured response, **TypeReference reference**) {

    String jsonString = response_I_got_via_RESTAssured.getBody();          
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,**reference**);    
  }
```

And it fixed an issue, all started worked OK again.

So my question is, why in general my 'error' variant of the method was working (I was debugging every step) and was failing only at the later findAny() step, when I was trying to filter the List I got?

Hope I explained my question clear, will really appreciate for the answer as I want to understand my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Because of type erasure, `T` becomes `Object` at runtime. If it was possible to infer the type from `T`, `readValue()` wouldn't bother asking for a `TypeReference`; it would create one internally just like you did. The point of `TypeReference` is to specify and capture the actual type at compile time so it can be referenced at runtime.

Comment: As for why it only failed at `findAny()`, that's the nature of heap pollution which is also a symptom of type erasure. The runtime doesn't know or care what type of stream it is until you try to extract the value and the internal cast fails. If you tried assigning the result to an `Object`, it wouldn't have to cast and it wouldn't fail.